# funcionalidades, objetos dentro de arrays

Tags: funciones, function, metodos

ayudenme a resolverlo, si alguien puede explicarme como hacerlo, gracias

**consigna:** Terminada esta función, María te pide que resuelvas la funcionalidad de totalDeVentas, que justamente nos devuelva la sumatoria del valor de todas las ventas realizadas. Acá el único requerimiento técnico explícito es que utilices la función reduce, ¡a codear!

**Errores que me saltan:**

.Al vender autos la función totalDeVentas retornar los valores adecuados

.Debes utilizar la función reduce() sobre los resultados de listaDeVentas

```
//este es el array y objeto literal, el cual es exportado
let autos =[{
marca:"Ford",
modelo: "Fiesta",
precio: 150000,
km: 200,  
color: "Azul", 
cuotas: 12, 
anio: 2019, 
patente: "APL123", 
vendido:false
},
{marca: "Toyota",
modelo: "Corolla",
precio: 100000,
km: 0,  
color: "Blanco", 
cuotas: 14, 
anio: 2019, 
patente:"JJK116" , 
vendido: false 
}]

   module.exports = autos
```

´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´

```
// este es mi codigo

 let concesionaria = {
 autos: autosImportados,

  buscarAuto: function(patentes){
  for (let i = 0; i< this.autos.length; i++){
  if (this.autos[i].patente === patentes){
return this.autos[i]    
}}},

  venderAuto:function (patente){
  let auto = this.buscarAuto (patente)
  if(auto){
     auto.vendido = true
  }
 },

  autosParaLaVenta:function(){
  return this.autos.filter(auto => !auto.vendido)
 },

  autosNuevos:function(){
        return this.autosParaLaVenta().filter((e => e.km < 100))},

 listaDeVentas: function(){
  return this.autos.filter(a => a.vendido).map(a=>a.precio)
},

 //lo de abajo es lo que no puedo resolver según la consigna, me sale error
  totalDeVentas:
  
  }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es _me sale error_? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. Además, agrega en las etiquetas qué lenguaje estás utilizando, ya que las etiquetas que agregaste son genéricas. Y por cierto, la consigna dice explícitamente _Acá el único requerimiento técnico explícito es que utilices la función reduce_. ¿La utilizaste?

Comment: `this.listaDeVentas.reduce((a,i)=>a+i)`